# Is it possible to pause co-routines in Unity until a button is pressed in unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to make a popup screen and I want to stop some code until a button is clicked on that popup screen is this possible. Would you show me some example code?

Comment: Just be aware that "pausing" a coroutine HAS NO MEANING.  A coroutine has utterly no connection to a "process" or anything like that.  It's just something that ***runs code, every frame of the game engine***.  Game engines are frame-based, and coroutines are literally just "how you access the frames".

Comment: Pause? Why not just start the coroutine once the button is clicked?  And what do you mean by **stop some code**? Show us some code, please.

Answer (score 1):

The code of your coroutine should look like this:

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    while(!buttonClickFlag)
    {
         yield return null;
    }
    //...
    buttonClickFlag = false;
    action();
}
```

When buttonClickFlag is set to true the action is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, after Unity 5.3 they added [WaitUntil](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) class and you can also use 'while' for waiting. Here is an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Popup : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button button;
    bool clicked;

    void Start(){
        button.onClick.AddListener (ClickButton);
        StartCoroutine (WaitUntilForClick ());
    }

    public void ClickButton(){
       clicked = true;
    }


    IEnumerator WaitUntilForClick(){

        #if UNITY_5_3_OR_NEWER
        yield return new WaitUntil (() => clicked);
        #else
        // Here you can cache WaitForEndOfFrame object
        WaitForEndOfFrame waitForFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        while(!clicked){
           yield return waitForFrame;
        }
        #endif

        Debug.Log ("after click");

    }

    void Update(){
        if(!clicked)
           Debug.Log ("waiting for click!");
    }
}
```